# How can I get image results on duckduckgo without javascript?

Tags: javascript, duckduckgo

How can I choose to search for "image results" on [DuckDuckGo](https://start.duckduckgo.com) with javascript disabled in my web browser?

For security reasons, I don't have javascript enabled in my browser. When I search for something, all I see at the top of the page is a drop-down menu to choose between regions and time. For example:

- https://html.duckduckgo.com/html?q=big+buck+bunny

If javascript is enabled, then you have the option to choose Images, Videos, News, and Maps. For example:

- https://duckduckgo.com/?q=big+buck+bunny

My question is: if javascript is disabled, then how can I force DDG to return image results?

Comment: Does not appear possible yet